# jquery get variable document ready

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-isotope

I have a problem to get a calculated variable on document ready.

I divide a container width by a number and I need to store this value then to used it after.

Here the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $layout = $('.container-scroll');
var $container = $('#container');
var $items = $('.element');
var $filter = $('#filter a');

function checkWidth() {

var windowSize = $(window).width(); 

if (windowSize <= 960) {    
    var $layout = $('.container-scroll');
    var colW = Math.round(($layout.width())/3)-1;       
    var ElementWidth = colW;
    var ElementHeight = Math.round(colW*0.6);
    $(".element").height(ElementHeight);
    $(".element").width(ElementWidth);  
    $(".element.square").height(ElementHeight * 2);
    $(".element.square").width(ElementWidth * 2);
    $(".element.wide").height(ElementHeight);
    $(".element.wide").width(ElementWidth * 2);
}
else if (windowSize > 960 && windowSize <= 1280 ) {
    var $layout = $('.container-scroll');
    var colW = Math.round(($layout.width())/4)-1;       
    var ElementWidth = colW;
    var ElementHeight = Math.round(colW*0.6);
    $(".element").height(ElementHeight);
    $(".element").width(ElementWidth);  
    $(".element.square").height(ElementHeight * 2);
    $(".element.square").width(ElementWidth * 2);
    $(".element.wide").height(ElementHeight);
    $(".element.wide").width(ElementWidth * 2);
}
else if (windowSize > 1280 && windowSize <= 1600 ) {
    var $layout = $('.container-scroll');
    var colW = Math.round(($layout.width())/5)-1;   
    var ElementWidth = colW;
    var ElementHeight = Math.round(colW*0.6);
    $(".element").height(ElementHeight);
    $(".element").width(ElementWidth);  
    $(".element.square").height(ElementHeight * 2);
    $(".element.square").width(ElementWidth * 2);
    $(".element.wide").height(ElementHeight);
    $(".element.wide").width(ElementWidth * 2);
}
else if (windowSize > 1600 ) {
    var $layout = $('.container-scroll');
    var colW = Math.round(($layout.width())/6)-1;   
    var ElementWidth = colW;
    var ElementHeight = Math.round(colW*0.6);
    $(".element").height(ElementHeight);
    $(".element").width(ElementWidth);  
    $(".element.square").height(ElementHeight * 2);
    $(".element.square").width(ElementWidth * 2);
    $(".element.wide").height(ElementHeight);
    $(".element.wide").width(ElementWidth * 2);
}
}

function checkIsotope() {
$container.isotope({
    perfectMasonry: {
    columnWidth: colW,
    rowHeight: colW,
    },
    masonryHorizontal: {
    rowHeight: colW,
    }
});
}

checkWidth();
checkIsotope();
var colW;
alert(colW)

$(window).smartresize(function() {
    checkWidth();
    checkIsotope()
})

}
```

I want to get var colW in order to definie my columnWidth and rowHeight in isotope layout.

When I put an alert on colW, colW is undefined...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var colW`  is a local variable

Try moving this out of your function

define your var like this :

```
var colW;
$(document).ready(function() {
......
```

and use this in your function

```
colW = Math.round(($layout.width())/4)-1;
```

You should be able to use this var for alert now.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I remove or move `var colW` nothing works after. And colW is still undefined.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It solve all my problems now. My script was good but it couldn't work without this GLOBAL variable!!!!